# tlmgr path add yields errors but makes symlinks

Tags: texlive, installing, paths

Today (June 9, 2016), I've just installed TeX Live 2016 on my Ubuntu 14.04.4. The installation itself was successful, but when I tried to make symlinks for binaries, info pages, and man pages, `path` subcommand from `tlmgr` failed (I mean, the exit status `$?` was `1` after the `path add`). Strangely, however, most of the symlinks were made in proper directories. Here is what I did in the terminal.

```
$ cd /path/to/installer
$ sudo ./install-tl
$ which tex
tex not found
$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr path add
tlmgr: action path returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
$ which tex
/usr/local/bin/tex
$ for file in $(ls /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/); do; which $file; done | grep "not found"
xindy.mem not found
```

I read [the documentation about `path`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/tlmgr.html#path---w32mode-user-admin-add-remove), but I couldn't understand what was wrong with my procedure.

The lack of `xindy.mem` in `$PATH` won't harm me because it's very unlikely for me to use `xindy` package, but what happened to my installation? Do I need to do something to fix this?

**Note (I'm not sure if this helps)**: Installing TeX Live 2015 on my El Capitan worked well in the exact same way a few months ago (the paths for `tlmgr` are different, of course).

---

On June 10, 2016, I tried re-installing TeX Live 2016 and could reproduce the same problem as yesterday.

```
$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr path remove
tlmgr: action path returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
$ which tex
tex not found
$ sudo mv /usr/local/texlive/2016 /usr/local/texlive/2016_bak
$ cd /path/to/installer
$ sudo ./install-tl
$ which tex
tex not found
$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr update --self --all
$ sudo /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/tlmgr path add
tlmgr: action path returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
$ which tex
/usr/local/bin/tex
$ LANG=C; for file in $(ls /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/); do; ls /usr/local/bin/$file; done | grep "No such file or directory"
ls: cannot access /usr/local/bin/man: No such file or directory
```

Regarding the last line, TeX Live 2015 on my El Capitan gives the same result. So, something seems wrong with the `path add` error on Linux.

```
$ for file in $(ls /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin/); do; ls /usr/local/bin/$file; done | grep "No such file or directory"
ls: /usr/local/bin/man: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are on Ubuntu and currently seem to try to convince Ubuntu to listen to commands written for Windows?

Comment: @KeksDose That's not what the manual page says, so if you are correct, the documentation is buggy. What the man page says is that `path` has different functionality on Windows than on Unix-type systems. On the latter, it creates symbolic links. On Windows, it does something different (which I won't try to explain because I won't understand it).

Comment: I assume that there was a problem, but not with the command which created the symlink for `tex`. Since `path add` tries to add a whole bunch of symbolic links, one or more of the others presumably failed. Personally, I've never used this. I just adjust my `PATH`. It would be helpful if the error message specified which bit had failed e.g. which links could not be created.

Comment: @cfr Your guess is right, one symlink was not created in `/usr/local/bin`. More detail is in the updated question. About the second point of your comment, I use `path add` because I like keeping environmental variables simple. That's just a personal preference, though.

Comment: You could try creating the symbolic link manually to see what the problem is. Does `xindy.mem` exist in `/usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/<whatever>/`?

Comment: @cfr Quite strange, but both `xindy.mem` and the symlink for it exist: `ls -l /usr/local/bin/xindy.mem` returns `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50  June  9 05:53 /usr/local/bin/xindy.mem -> /usr/local/texlive/2016/bin/x86_64-linux/xindy.mem` At the same time, `which xindy.mem` says `xindy.mem not found` although `/usr/local/bin` is listed in `PATH`...

Comment: I'm not sure about the date format of `ls -l` because it's written in Japanese on my screen.

Comment: `which` will only return executables. `xindy.mem` is not marked as executable.

Comment: Note that, according to the man page, `path add` shouldn't only create symlinks for `bin/` but also some other things (man pages or info or something - run `tlmgr --help` for details).

Comment: `lrwxrwxrwx` says `/usr/local/bin/xindy.mem` is executable for everyone, doesn't it? I'm afarid I don't know the function of it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in current `tlmgr` (or at least two would be better) that returns an error during the action `tlmgr path add`. Thanks for the report, I will fix it (in due time). I have checked the source but didn't find any obvious bug, but I will eventually fix it as I see the same behaviour.

Why on your side xindy.mem wasn't linked is strange, because in my case it was indeed linked.

Hope that helps

Norbert

Comment: As I mentioned in [this comment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/313678/tlmgr-path-add-yields-errors-but-makes-symlinks#comment764781_313678), `xindy.mem` seemed to be linked. I'm not sure about the result of the second trial, however, so I will check it tomorrow. Glad to hear that you recognize this problem and that it doesn't happen to only me, anyway.

Comment: Running the command `tlmgr path add` after failing to initiate symlinks during install, on Ubuntu 16.04, I just received the error:  `tlmgr: action path returned an error; continuing.`.
However, upon running `which tex`, I see that the symlinks were created (i.e. a path is now given, which wasn't the case before).